# How to partially override some methods of a class for testing in C# while keeping the original class definition intact?

Tags: c#, testing, mocking

#### Problem

We would like to find a way to selectively override some methods of a class but not changing a bit of its definition.
Also, we would like the overriding to be optional (i.e. not obligatory). That is, we can override it whenever we want to, but we can also choose not to write any line of code for it when we don't want to.

#### Use case

Assume we have a class that provides data, let's call it `Model`.
We have another class that consumes these data. It is `View`.

Now, we would like to do integration tests for the `View`. For convenience, we would like to change some portion of the data provided by `Model` while keeping other part as-is.
Because we want to change the data returned by `Model`, it means we have to override some of its behavior (i.e. methods). However, because this is just a test, naturally we do not want to modify the source code of `Model`.

#### Previous Attemps

##### Decorator

The first approach I could think of is extracting an interface for `Model`, say `IModel`, and create a decorator for it, such as

```
public interface IModel
{
    string GetSomething();
    string GetOther(); // We want to override this
}

public class Model : IModel // This is the real model
{
}

public class ModelWrapper : IModel
{
    private IModel _internal; // Should be an instance of Model

    public string GetSomething() => _internal.GetSomething(); // we want to keep the behavior of original model for this method

    public string GetOther() // We want to change the behavior of this one
    {
        return "something for testing";
    }
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that we will have full control of the mock.
However, the downside would be that we have to keep maintaining the `ModelWrapper`.
When `IModel` is changed, we are forced to update `ModelWrapper`.
Unfortunately, we have many `IModel` and they do change frequently. Maintaining these wrapper classes is quite disturbing.

##### Mocking Library

Another approach I could think of would be using a mocking library to do it, such as NSubtitute or Moq.
With mocking library, we can specify behavior of methods of an interface without changing any code of its implementing classes.

We don't have to specify the behavior of every method of an interface. We can mock them selectively.
The behavior of the unmocked methods are automatically decided by the mock library.
Usually they simply return the default value of the returning type.

However, default values might not be good enough for us sometimes because we might need them to be in some specific range, or the `IView` would look weird.
A better fallback might be using our (existing) concrete classes. They usually do generate the correct results.

So far, I cannot find a mocking library that can fallback to a concrete class. NSubstitute & Moq support the following two things, but they are not quite ideal:

1. Mock for an interface. Methods that are not explicitly mocked returns default values. The view might look weird.
2. Mock for a class. Only virtual methods can be overridden. We need to change the code of our concrete classes if we want to mock them in this way.

What are the other good ways of achieving this goal?
Or am I solving the wrong problem? Maybe there are some other methods to address such testing needs?

Comment: Why do you want to override *parts* of the model? Could you describe a use-case? Typically when doing integration testing you would use components as is, or mock whole components, like the database.

Comment: The use-case is that we are working on GUIs and want to polish and test states of each "page" of them separately.
For example, let's assume we are building StackOverflow and are working on the QuestionListPage. It might consume an Account model, which contains a user profile and a list of questions that the user asked/answered. 
When we are polishing the page, we don't need to set the profile part to be certain values. But it should be "normal" since the page displays user info. On the other hand, we might want to configure the question list part to test various cases rapidly.

Answer (score 0):

If the class is not sealed, you can make the methods you want to override, virtual, and then override them in a derived class. That would have minimal impact on the source code and woulld not need any library.

Note that the derived class should only be used to tests, and should be excluded from the final code, maybe using `internal`.
This is a simple solution, but kinda unneficient and isn't a real class mock, just a simple overriding to do some experiments and tests.

Comment: Thanks. This is indeed a viable solution. However, the virtuals could be misleading for other developers. We don't really want the methods to be replaced in production code but the virtuals are required for testing...

Comment: Then these virtual methods could be "decorated" with a ConditionalAttribute("DEBUG"), so that is filtered out to only exist in debugging, not in production.

Comment: ConditionalAttribute is cool! I did not think about that. But, if I use the ConditionalAttribute, the virtual methods will be debugging only, right? That is, its caller (the IView) should also be debug only. At least the IView would behave differently in the debugging and production mode. Wouldn't it break the purpose of mocking?

Comment: Not really, if you define a symbol with #define and set the argument to the conditional attribute to the name of the symbol, that would tests it, and when you are distributing it, you could just undefine it, or comment the #define